# How to ignore svn merge options?

Tags: svn, unix, command-line, merge

I'm trying to merge a range of revs into my local work space. I want to ignore the conflict options and let it merge with conflicts so that i can resolve all at once later.

How to do it?

```
svn merge -r N:N-1 <URL> 
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
    (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
    (s) show all options: p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--accept` parameter in the `svn merge` command to eliminate conflict questions. This will postpone all conflicts:

```
svn merge --accept postpone -r N:N-1 <URL>
```

You can also *accept* automatically too:

```
svn merge --accept theirs-conflict -r N:N-1 <URL>
svn merge --accept theirs-full -r N:N-1 <URL>
svn merge --accept mine-full -r N:N-1 <URL>
svn merge --accept base -r N:N-1 <URL>
svn merge --accept working -r N:N-1 <URL>
```

Comment: `theirs-conflict (tc)` - does it mean get latest from server ? like right.merge block ?

Comment: @iaav `theirs-conflict` means when there's a conflict to use the version you're merging from instead of the version you're merging to. If you say `theirs-full`, you are taking the entire file when there's a merge conflict. See [Resolve Any Conflicts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve) in the Subversion manual.

Comment: Most of my developers say to use latest from svn server in event of conflict. So `--accept theirs-full` is appropriate, right ?

Comment: @iaav -- All depends. If my branch is suppose to be a duplicate of the branch I'm merging from, I use `--accept theirs-full`. If my branch and their branch both fixed the same bug, but my fix is better, I do `--accept mine-full`. If a change on their branch is something I might want to keep, but I want my fix over theirs, it's `--accept mine-conflicts.` If I made a change, and they also made a change, I probably want to manually do the change, `--accept edit`. The golden rule: Understand what's causing the conflict before you `--accept` anything.